# Optimize a function that acts on a numpy array with an if statement

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have a code like:

```
import numpy as np

def value_error(x):
    if x > 10:
        return 0.
    else:
        return np.sin(x)
```

This could give me a `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()` if called upon an numpy array.

Now I could do this instead:

```
def alright(x):
    return np.sin(x) * (x <= 10.)

print alright(np.ones(100) * 100)
print value_error(np.ones(100) * 10)
```

My function (in this case `np.sin`) could be an expensive one. It is, however, called for every element of `x`, even ones where I know the answer because `x > 10`, without an expensive call. How can I get the best of both worlds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a mask based one that operates with `np.sin` only on the valid ones -

```
out = np.zeros(x.shape)
mask = x <= 10
out[mask] = np.sin(x[mask])
```

Leveraging [`numexpr` module](http://numexpr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#how-it-works) for faster `transcendental` operations -

```
import numexpr as ne

out = np.zeros(x.shape)
mask = x <= 10
x_masked = x[mask]
out[mask] = ne.evaluate('sin(x_masked)')
```

Comment: Why is `numexpr` faster for `sin`? My understanding was that it only helped for compound expressions

Comment: @Eric Why its faster with transcendental ones (sin, etc)? No idea, but it seems to be. Not sure we can dig deep to find out though.

Answer (score 4):

Many of the `ufunc` take a `where` parameter

```
In [98]: x=np.arange(10)*2
In [99]: mask = x<10
In [100]: y = np.zeros(10)
In [101]: np.sin(x,where=mask,out=y)
Out[101]: 
array([ 0.        ,  0.90929743, -0.7568025 , -0.2794155 ,  0.98935825,
        0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ])
```

While this is a small case, `timeit` suggests it doesn't have much advantage over the `mask` use of `@divakar's answer:

```
In [104]: timeit np.sin(x,where=mask,out=y)
5.17 µs ± 12.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [105]: timeit y[mask] = np.sin(x[mask])
4.69 µs ± 9.54 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

(for much larger `x`, the `where` parameter has a slight time advantage over the `mask` use.)

Answer (score 2):

Note that your function does not take advantage of numpy's vectorisation. There are a few possible options.

**Option 1**
This seems like a good use case for `np.where` -

```
y = np.where(x > 10, 0, np.sin(x))
```

Which returns values based on the mask provided. Here's a sample -

```
x
array([  0.1,   0.2,   0.3,  11. ,   0.1,  11. ])

np.where(x > 10, 0, np.sin(x))
array([ 0.09983342,  0.19866933,  0.29552021,  0.        ,  0.09983342,  0.        ])
```

Note that this method still calls the "expensive function" for each element.

---

**Option 2**
Another possibility is to use a mask and set values conditionally -

```
y = np.sin(x)
y[x > 10] = 0
```

Similar to above, you could multiply `x` by a mask and call `np.sin` on the result -

```
y = np.sin(x * (x < 10))
```

As Divakar mentioned, you can use numexpr with this condition -

```
import numexpr as ne
y = ne.evaluate("sin(x * (x < 10))")
```

This should be faster than the ones above.

Comment: So fast! Thanks!

Comment: For transcendental ones, `numexpr` could be helpful.

Comment: @Divakar I've not worked with this before, but it looks cool! How would you get it to work with a condition? `ne.evaluate("sin(x) if x < 10 else 0")` seems to not be right.

Comment: I guess it would work better with the mask one, as suggested at the end of the post.

Comment: These methods still call the 'expensive' function on all values of `x`.