# python: Conditional plus operator for numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I want to apply the plus operator on two numpy arrays. However, there is a constriction.
I want to sum up the element only if it is not zero in array one. I could do this in a loop, but this is very slow. Is there a numpy typical approach?

```
if a1[xyz] != 0:
    r[xyz] = a1[xyz] + a2[xyz]
```

Comment: I think you are looking for  `np.where`

Comment: Use masking : `r = a1 + a2*(a1!=0)`, for zeros intialized `r`.

Comment: @Divakar OP's code seems to update an existing `r` not touching the values where `a1==0`

Comment: @PaulPanzer That's why the qualifier at the end of comment.

Comment: @Divakar, sorry, missed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a mask:

```
mask = a1 != 0
r[mask] = a1[mask] + a2[mask]
```

This assumes that `r, a1, a2` have the same shapes.

Comment: Thanks, weirdly I seems to break if I add more than one condition: mask = (img_array == 0 or img_array == 1)
Do you know why?

Comment: `or` doesn't work element-wise. You must use `|`. Because of operator precedence you will then also have to put parentheses around the individual conditions.

Answer (score 2):

An other fast way : `np.where(a1==0,r,a1+a2)`.

Answer (score 0):

As I noted in [Optimize a function that acts on a numpy array with an if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47744927/optimize-a-function-that-acts-on-a-numpy-array-with-an-if-statement), many `ufunc` take a `where` parameter

In this case we can use `np.add` in such a way:

```
In [168]: r = np.arange(10)
In [169]: a1 = np.ones(10,int); a1[3:7]=0
In [170]: mask = a1.astype(bool)
In [171]: mask
Out[171]: array([ True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
In [172]: a2 = np.arange(10,20)

In [173]: a1+a2
Out[173]: array([11, 12, 13, 13, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20])
In [174]: np.add(a1,a2)
Out[174]: array([11, 12, 13, 13, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20])

In [175]: np.add(a1,a2, where=mask, out=r);
In [176]: r
Out[176]: array([11, 12, 13,  3,  4,  5,  6, 18, 19, 20])
```

Without the `out`, the `where` leaves 'random' values in the masked out elements.

In the previous post this `where` has about the same timing as the `masked` equivalent.

If you want to use a compound mask, try something like `mask = (a1!=0) & (a2>15)`.  The () are important.